# How to make Menu satay active even after clicking on it's MenuItems in Sencha ExtReact?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extreact

here's the code exam:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Button text="Menu">
                    <Menu rel="menu" activeChildTabIndex="1" >
                        <MenuItem text="Mobile" name="ui-type" />
                        <MenuItem text="Desktop" name="ui-type"/>
                    </Menu>
                </Button>
            </Container>
        )
    }
```

and I would like to know How to make my Menu stay active even after I clicked on any of its menuItems? 
any ideas?

[image: this is how it looks now]

you can play [here in Sencha fiddle](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.5.1/modern/Ext.menu.Item.html)

Answer (score 1):

we need to put and to set **hideOnClick={false}** and that's it :)

```
 <MenuItem  hideOnClick={false} text="randomText" />
```